# How to use Data scraping (UIPATH) to get data from a certain range of pages (page 11 to page 20)?

Tags: uipath

I'm trying to use the data scraping wizard in UiPath to get the details of books from pages 11 to 20, after applying filters, and input them in an Excel file. I've tried putting the data scraping activity in a loop, I've tried using a counter for the selector of the page, but none of them worked. Can anyone help?

[url of book store](https://www.dymocks.com.au/books)

Answer (score 0):

First of all you need to navigate on the start page (for example page 11) and set the scraping data on a single page.
Instead to select the next button in the data scraping wizard you leave the scraping for only one page.
Then you could loop these previous steps in a "for each" or "while" where you change dinamically the navigation path and attach browser element.
The loop could start dinamically from a integer counter (from 11 to 20).

Comment: that is genius!!!!! why didnt i think of that???!?!?!?!?!